# Autotools include header file

Tags: c, autotools

I have a directory structure like

```
Makefile.am
Configure.ac
     src/
         add.c
         add.h
         Makefile.am

     tests/
         test.c
         Makefile.am
```

test/Makefile.am :

```
AM_CFLAGS = -Wall -lcunit
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/src  
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = tests.c src/add.h
test_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)
```

tests/test.c

```
#include "src/add.h"
```

src/add.h :

```
int addNum(int a, int b);
```

When I make file is giving error

```
undefined reference to `addNum'
```

Comment: I assume that somewhere in the `test.c` source, you actually call the `addNum` function. Then you need the *definition* of the function, not only the declaration. All the declaration does is tell the compiler that a function exists, it's then up to the linker to actually find the function definition and if it's not found (because you don't link with the object file created from `add.c` (where I assume the definition is)) you get the error.

Comment: You've shown you have a declaration, where is the definition of `int addNum`? Do you compile and link that file properly?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I did have  call the `addNum` function in `tests/test.c`, how to link object file in `Makefile.am`.Thanks.

Comment: Add the `add.c` *source* file to `test_SOURCES`, not the header file.

Comment: I modify `test_SOURCES = tests.c src/add.h src/add.c` ,but it tell 
`No rule to make target 'src/add.c', needed by 'test-add.o'`.What am i miss?

Comment: In `tests/Makefile.am`, you want to refer to `add.c` as `$(top_srcdir)/src/add.c`.  The include search path is not used to locate it.  Similar goes for `add.h`, the include search path notwithstanding.